# How do I include a timer from start to finish of the sub? Each call is a separate sub

Tags: excel, vba

I need the timer function included to compute the total time it takes to run the macro from WbtoWb2 to WbtoWb10...what code would be needed to include?

```
 Sub ComparisonTemplate()
    Call WbtoWb2
    Call WbtoWb3
    Call WbtoWb4
    Call WbtoWb5
    Call WbtoWb6
    Call WbtoWb7
    Call WbtoWb8
    Call WbtoWb9
    Call WbtoWb10
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+timer&oq=excel+vba+timer&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7041j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) that for you.

Answer (score 4):

Record the start time, figure the elapsed time between the end and the recorded start time...

```
Sub ComparisonTemplate()
    Dim startTime : startTime = Now()
    Call WbtoWb2
    Call WbtoWb3
    Call WbtoWb4
    Call WbtoWb5
    Call WbtoWb6
    Call WbtoWb7
    Call WbtoWb8
    Call WbtoWb9
    Call WbtoWb10
    MsgBox "Finished in " & DateDiff("s", startTime, Now()) & " seconds."
End Sub
```

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  This will reward @Dave for his effort and help others with the same problem to find the correct answer.